# Setting custom properties on EntityFrameworkCore Model

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am having a table to store individual pages of courses. The table looks like :

```
Pages :
---------------------------------------------------
CourseId | LessonId | TopicId | Url
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     1    |    0    | lesson-1
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     1    |    1    | lesson-1-Topic-1
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     1    |    2    | lesson-1-Topic-2 
---------------------------------------------------      
    1    |     1    |    3    | lesson-1-Topic-3
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     2    |    0    | lesson-2
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     2    |    1    | lesson-2-Topic-1
---------------------------------------------------
    1    |     2    |    2    | lesson-2-Topic-2
---------------------------------------------------
```

The CourseId, LessonId & TopicId are integers and constitute the Primary Key for the table. This model enables me to quickly know the lesson, the topic serial no. , topics in a lesson.

I wish to have entity model like :

```
Public class Page
{
   public int CourseId {get;set;}
   public int LessonId {get;set;}
   public int TopicId {get;set;}

   // Need to write custom logic to fetch and set below properties
   // Whenever this entity is initialized
   public Page PreviousPage {get;set;}
   public Page NextPage {get;set;}
   public Page LessonPage {get;set;}
   public ICollection<Page> ChildPages {get;set;}
}
```

How can i set these custom properties within the model ? We can query the DB in the controller and set these properties. Wouldn't that push the application logic in the controller ?

**Platform / libraries** : Asp.Net Core 2.0, MySQL 5.7, Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.Mysql

Comment: These don't look appropriate for entity model (misleading, look like navigation properties etc.) Better remove them and create DTO / ViewModel. And populate them with query (the exact place is not important as soon as you have access to the entity model `IQueryable`).

Comment: I wouldn't even store the data that way. There are two 1:n relationships here, so I'd store them as such and shape the data client-side as desired. In case you're looking for it: there's no way to do this with some EF mapping.

Comment: @GertArnold Any suggestions to handle this better ?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve in a wider sense ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/168269)). The structure as you show above may not be the best starting point.

Comment: @GertArnold in my question please refer to class Page. I wish to have the PreviousPage, NextPage, LessonPage and ChildPages property. How should i design the entity and table to achieve this ?